# strange issue with embedded ruby tags

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, jruby, erb

i have started using rails 3.1.3. After running the first sample application, I saw all my ruby tags in html.erb files are strangely converted into  `tag. 
for e.g.`

```
<%= render :partial=> "abc.html" %> is converting to

<code> render :partial => "abc.html" %><code> in html output...
```

This seems very strange to me.. Am i missing something or what?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to name your file the right thing?  I think the new standard is something like `filename.html.erb`.

Comment: yes files are named like that only. actually i am using spree e-commerce solution with rails 3.1.3 gem. Everything gone smoothly but stuck here. this code is from spree gem only which is giving such a strange output.